Consequences of concurrent fsync on the same fd
What does happen if two threads call fsync on the same entity simultaneously? For example, they want to synchronize the same directory at the same time, when they create new files in it. I have checked manpage and found nothing about concurrency.

As fsync() operates on a file-descriptor, any pending information to be written is stored in kernel-space. Which thread requires this pending information to be written does not really matter. On the other hand, if some buffering is performed in user-space, fsync() won't consider it at all (it acts at a lower level).

On the other hand, if some buffering is performed in user-space, fsync() won't consider it at all (it acts at a lower level) Do you mean something like creating an array or a buffer in a programs instead of explicitly opening a file descriptor?

I was thinking about using something like a BufWriter around the file-descriptor. Using fsync() on the underlying file-descriptor won't flush the BufWriter.

However, as to yur first point: As fsync() operates on a file-descriptor, any pending information to be written is stored in kernel-space. Which thread requires this pending information to be written does not really matter. Does fsync save data in an atomic way? I think I still don't get it why multiple threads are not a problem

The multiple threads using the same file-descriptor refer to the same entry in the open-file table of the kernel. The kernel certainly uses the proper internal locking when accessing this entry (write() calls from multiple threads or processes if the fd is inherited) and eventually keeping some of its data in a kernel-space buffer. When fsync() is called, the same internal locking is probably used.

Did you experience some inconsistencies/race-conditions when invoking fsync() concurrently?

No, I have never experienced, at least I can't recall such problems. I have raised the question during the planning phase of the project implementation.
